# Java8 transform a [List<Object>, String] in a Map<Object, String>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Computer>`. Every Computer has a list of CPU and a hostname.
So,suppose I have:

```
List<Computer> computers
```

I can call

```
List<CPU> CPUs = computer.getCPUs();
```

and I can call

```
String hostname = computer.getHostName();
```

What I want to do is, using Streams, obtain a Map that contains as key the CPU and as String the hostname. Same CPU inside the same Computers will replicate the hostname.

How can I do that?

Pre Java8 code would be this:

```
public Map<CPU, String> getMapping(List<Computer> computers) {
    Map<CPU, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Computer computer : computers) {
        for (CPU cpu : computer.getCPUs()) {
            result.put(cpu, computer.getHostname());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `computer` and `computers`.  If you want your question to survive add pre-Java 8 code that accomplishes your task.

Comment: thanks, I added pre Java8 code

Comment: I think there's no streams & lambdas solution better than the one you already have

Comment: What happens If the same CPU links to more than two Hostnames?

Answer (score 1):

If your `CPU` class has a back-reference to it's `Computer` instance, then you can do this easily. First stream over all the computers, and flat-map with `getCPUs`, this will give you a `Stream<CPU>` of all CPUs. Then you can use `Collectors.toMap` to collect into a `Map<CPU, String>` using `Function.identity` for the key and a lambda extracting first the `Computer` and then the hostname from the CPU for the value.
In code:

```
computers.stream()
    .flatMap(computer -> computer.getCPUs().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), cpu -> cpu.getComputer().getHostname()));
```

Comment: What leads you to the assumption that there is a `cpu.getComputer()` method?

Comment: As I explained in the first sentence, I assumed this because it is a reasonable assumption and necessary for this to be solvable cleanly with the Stream API. If such a method does not exist, the stream pipeline would get more inefficient, because I don't think you could do it without an intermediate collect step.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by implementing your own `Collector` in order to assign the same value to all the CPUs of the same computer:

```
Map<CPU, String> cpus = computers.stream().collect(
    Collector.of(
        HashMap::new,
        // Put each cpu of the same computer using the computer's hostname as value
        (map, computer) -> computer.getCPUs().stream().forEach(
            cpu -> map.put(cpu, computer.getHostName())
        ),
        (map1, map2) -> { map1.putAll(map2); return map1; }
    )
);
```

This is basically the equivalent of what you currently do using the `Stream API`, the only difference is the fact that you could parallelize it by simply using a parallel stream instead of a normal stream, but in this particular case as the tasks are quite small, it would probably not help much in term of performances such that using the `Stream API` in this case could be considered as a little bit abusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an intermediate `Entry` to hold the CPU and hostname together:

```
Map<CPU, String> map = computers.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> c.getCPUs().stream().map(cpu -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(cpu, c.getHostName())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```